# htaccess - rewrite urls with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a rewrite of `/example-friendly-url` to display the content of `/posts.php?id=1`.

Both the friendly url value and the id are stored in a mysql table.

Here's what I've written so far but something's not right:

posts.php:

```
include('/functions.php');
$post = getPost($_GET['id']);
$param = getSlug($_GET['param']);
```

functions.php:

```
function getPost($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

function getSlug($param) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM list WHERE slug = '$param'") or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/posts.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/posts.php?param=$1 [NC,L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: whats not right? try to echo out what you read from the database.

Comment: Provide a sample of the URL that you want rewritten. `/example-friendly-url` is not helpful.

Comment: So the rewrite loads posts.php but none of the content loads from the database and the homepage is caught in the rewrite which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

The leading slash is removed when mod_rewrite rules are processed in an htaccess file, so you don't want the `^/` in front of the regex:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/posts.php?param=$1 [NC,L]
```

You are passing a "slug" as `_GET['param']`. There's no "id". What you need to do in your `posts.php` is turn that slug into an ID:

```
include('/functions.php');

$post_id = getSlug($_GET['param']);
$post = getPost($post_id);
```

Of course, making sure that `$_GET['param']` is sanitized, using something like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (deprecated, you really want to be using [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)).